# phonegap chat application user can see others message

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, ajax, cordova

I am using phonegap to develop an one to one chat application. My problem is when user click a contact and send a message. Then user click go back button and click another contact it can still see the message which he just sent to the first user.

Here is a part of my code:

Here is using ajax to get contact from server.When it success,it will generate a list view to show all contacts.

```
$.each(contacts, function(i,item)
{
  output += '<li  data-name='+item+'><a href="#chat_page">' + item + '</a></li>';
  $('#contacts_list').html(output).listview('refresh');
  //Show the contact name on the front of chat page
  $('#contacts_list').children('li').on('click', function ()
  {
    var contact_name=$(this).attr('data-name');
    $('#contact_name').html(contact_name);
    get_name(contact_name);
  });
});
```

```
<!--When someone click a user in contacts, it will show the chat page-->
<div data-role="page" id="chat_page" data-role="page" data-theme="a">
<div data-role="header">
  <h1 id="contact_name"></h1>
</div>

<div data-role="content">
  <div id="incomingMessages" name="incomingMessages" class="msgContainerDiv" > 
  </div>
  <label for="messageText"><strong>Message:</strong></label>
  <textarea id="messageText"></textarea>

</div>

<div data-role="footer">

  <fieldset class="ui-grid-a">
    <div class="ui-block-a">
      <a href="#contacts_page" id="goBackButton" data-role="button">Go Back</a>  
    </div>
    <div class="ui-block-b">
      <button data-theme="a" id="chatSendButton" name="chatSendButton">Send
</input>
  </fieldset>

</div>

</div>
```

And here is part of ajax code where I using ajax to get chat data, then append them in to my chat page.

```
success: function(data)
                 {
                 var get_data = JSON.parse(data);

                 $("#incomingMessages").append
                 (
                  "<div class='message'><span class='username'>" +
                  (get_data.from || 'Anonymous') +"</span> : " +
                  (get_data.message || ' ') + "</br>" +
                  (get_data.message_time || ' ')
                  +"</div>"
                  );
                 }
                 });
```

I know the reason is when user click contact it will always go to the same page and that is why message can be seen to all of users.

Is there any solution for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably unrelated, but your html is incorrect. There is a rogue `</input>`, the div inside the fieldset is not closed within the fieldset and there is a rogue `</div>` and the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution will be to use local storage to store the history (`#incomingMessages`) and `#messageText` for each user.

Then you can clear `#messageText` and just reload it when the user reopens the chat.

Answer (score 0):

You should clear `#incomingMessages` when you switch users. You are likely leaving the HTML content in that div when you want to be replacing it with the new user's messages.

Something like

`$('#incomingMessages').html('')`

Comment: I have thought about it. What I did is $('#goBackButton').click(function()
{                                                       $('.message').empty();                                                          $("#messageText").val('');
});
However if I do like this, user will can not see his history chat messages because it has been set to empty.

Comment: The only way I think can solve is do like you said and then using ajax to get history messages from server when user click contact name.But I think there must be a better solution.